# Export a Java library as an ES module in Graalvm/graaljs

Tags: graalvm, graaljs

Is there some way to setup a Java object as a "module" for graaljs?
Like, if I had a class like this

```java
public class JavaLib {
    public static String foo() {
        return "foo";
    }

    public static String bar() {
        return "bar";
    }

}
```

is there some combination of Proxy objects or annotations that I could wire up such that my script could do this:

```js
import {foo} form 'JavaLib'
let x = foo()
```